# Understanding NgSwitch in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, ng-switch

Hello i got an error as i am trying to learn angular2. I decided to have a go at replacing child components within a parent component. Both child component A and B will replace each other using the in built `ngSwitch`. But i got an error complaining about its not a native property binding to both child-componentA and child-componentB. It seems to fail to bind the property to both child components. But below i came across a solution that works but don't understand why the latter works. I followed the tutorials from angular2. Could someone explain why the first failed and second solution provided worked. Thanks.

parent.html

```
<div class= "col-md-4" [ngSwitch]="componentNumber">
  <child-componentA *ngSwitchCase="1"> </child-componentA>
  <child-componentB *ngSwitchCase="2"> </child-componentB>
</div>
```

component.ts file of parent:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
//metadata tags defined but didn't need to include

export class Parent  {

   componentNumber: number = 1;

    ChangeComponent(value: number) {
       this.componentNumber = value;
    }
}
```

The code below solved my issue but i am failing to understand why the previous code above failed as i followed the examples from anuglar docs

Solved problem using the code below:

```
<div class="col-md-4" [ngSwitch]="componentNumber">
    <template>
       <child-componentA [ngSwitchWhen]="1"></child-componentA>
     </template>
    <template>
      <child-componentB [ngSwitchWhen]="2"></child-componentB>
    </template>
  </div>
```

Comment: So your question is, why using the wrong syntax didn't work? I don't see how `*ngSwitch` should've worked. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

Comment: @rinukkusu sorry meant ngSwitchCase but it didn't work

Comment: @rinukkusu *ngSwitchCase didn't work when i used it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest RC4 version, check this documentation for [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)